# How to use node modules in Scala.js

Tags: node.js, scala, scala.js

I just started to use Scala.js and want to port an existing node based JavaScript app to Scala.js. The first problem: I need to include the mysql module https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql to access MySQL from Scala.js.

Comment: This should help you: https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/module.html

Comment: This link Is about emitting a module and not about how to use an existing one.

Comment: You need to emit a module to be able to import other modules. There is a link from that page to further documentation on `@JSImport` which shows how to define types for things you need to import.

Comment: To be able to further help you, it would be good to edit your question with a concrete example of a module you wish to import, and what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 7):

This takes a few steps:

- add the [`ScalaJSBundlerPlugin`](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/reference.html) to your `plugins.sbt` ([example](https://github.com/ebruchez/tessel-display/blob/323035d68fe4f2127b8b7781c0cf9a6744ce744c/project/plugins.sbt))
- enable the plugin in your `build.sbt` ([example](https://github.com/ebruchez/tessel-display/blob/323035d68fe4f2127b8b7781c0cf9a6744ce744c/build.sbt#L2))
- create a facade (which can be minimal) for your Node module ([example for `node-fetch`](https://github.com/ebruchez/tessel-display/blob/323035d68fe4f2127b8b7781c0cf9a6744ce744c/src/main/scala/org/bruchez/tessel/NodeFetch.scala) ) defining an object with something like `@JSImport("node-fetch", JSImport.Namespace)`
- add `npmDependencies` in your `build.sbt` ([example](https://github.com/ebruchez/tessel-display/blob/323035d68fe4f2127b8b7781c0cf9a6744ce744c/build.sbt#L13))
- create a custom webpack config which configures node as a target ([example](https://github.com/ebruchez/tessel-display/blob/323035d68fe4f2127b8b7781c0cf9a6744ce744c/tessel.webpack.config.js))